# Simple non-tracking reference cannot be bound to an entity on the managed heap

Tags: c++-cli, pinvoke

I am writing C++/CLI code using C++ Interop (Implicit P/Invoke) and I am getting the error "simple non-tracking reference cannot be bound to an entity on the managed heap". Here's the offending code:

```
public ref class ManagedClass
    {
    private:

        UInt32 _handle;

    public:

        short __clrcall ManagedFunc(UInt32 timeout)
        {
            return native(_handle, timeout);
        }
    };
```

when trying to call a native function with signature:

```
short native(unsigned long& handle, unsigned long timeout);
```

I understand that the error is saying don't use a managed type in an unmanaged function. I can get around it by changing ManagedFunc like so:

```
short __clrcall ManagedFunc(UInt32 timeout)
{
        unsigned long handle;
        auto retval = native(handle, timeout);
        _handle = handle;
        return retval;
}
```

But that is a bit ugly to have to declare a native type, call the function and store the return value, copy the native value to managed memory, and return the value. Is there a cleaner way to do the above using C++ Interop (Implicit P/Invoke)?

Comment: You actually used `handle` in the native() call.  It has the same potential problem as the first snippet, if native() stores the handle value itself then you have a dangling pointer bug.  It dangles because the reference becomes invalid after the function returns.  The first snippet dangles as well, now properly diagnosed instead of UB, happens when the garbage collector moves the object.  But it is somewhat likely that native() is actually a handle-based allocate_object() kind of function, for which the second snippet is a correct workaround.  A uint32* member is safe either way, not better.

Comment: @Hans Passant that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!